# Leaflet - Zoom/Pan to Layer Extent when Toggling Layers

Tags: leaflet, fitbounds

I am working on a bus route map, and have several routes that users can turn on and off.  I would like to work out how to zoom/pan so that the chosen route (or routes) are fully on screen when chosen. (some are off screen with the initial zoom level).

Here's the magic so far:

```
var busRoute10 = L.geoJson([route10, busStop3, busStop4],{onEachFeature: onEachFeature});
var busRoute11 = L.geoJson([route11, busStop19, busStop16, busStop18, busStop22],{onEachFeature: onEachFeature});
var busRoute12 = L.geoJson([route12, busStop23, busStop42, busStop43, busStop15, busStop28, busStop27, busStop22, busStop16],{onEachFeature: onEachFeature});
var busRoute13 = L.geoJson([route13, busStop44, busStop31, busStop25, busStop26, busStop36],{onEachFeature: onEachFeature});


var baseLayers = {
"Route 10": busRoute10,
"Route 11": busRoute12,
"Route 12<hr>": busRoute14,
"Route 13": busRoute20,
};

L.control.layers(null, baseLayers, {collapsed: false}).setPosition ('topright').addTo(map);
```

I've tried multiple combinations of map.fitBounds, and just can't seem to get it.

Also, is there a way to add a title and subtitles to the control box?  I'd like to have the contols look like:

Day
[]Route 10
[]Route 11
Night
[]Route 12...  etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should attach a listener on map's [`"overlayadd"`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-layers-overlayadd) event. Then you can do your `map.fitBounds()` using the `event.layer.getBounds()`, since your layers are GeoJSON groups.

As for organizing your layers in the Layers Control, it is not possible with the default control. But you can have a look at [Leaflet plugins](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html).